# Can we use BNF for parsing AND lexing instead of regex?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

With a Backus-Naur form grammar (BNF), we can specify the syntax of the programming language in order to **parse** it and produce an abstract syntax tree (AST).

```
<if> ::= "if" <expression> "then" <action> "end"
```

But we can also specify the tokens with a BNF grammar, as the first usage of BNF did for ALGOL-60:

```
<digit> ::= "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
<digit_with_zero> ::= <digit> | "0"
<integer> ::= <digit> | <digit_with_zero> <integer>
```

However, this usage of the BNF in order to **lex** (= produce a list of minimal meaningful units aka tokens) has been deprecated in favor of regular expressions (like [1-9][0-9]*).

It seems clear that the regex are much more concise.

It seems also that keeping the structure of an if statement is interesting for the interpreter or the compiler which will handle the AST produced by the parser, but keeping the structure of an integer (or a float) is not.

But do you agree that BNF could be used for both lexing and parsing?
And do you agree with the reasons which make regex much more suited for lexing?
Or are there others?

Comment: Of course, but it's more powerful than required. BNF allows you to define CFGs but all you need for lexics is regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions (in the mathematical sense) are equivalent in power to regular grammars and regular grammars can be written in BNF. So in that sense, it is clearly possible to write a full grammar for any context-free language in pure BNF.

Indeed, it is not even necessary to maintain the lexer/parser dichotomy. Some programmers find it convenient to use [scannerless parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scannerless_parsing) (the article is not great but it has some interesting references), although many of these are based on the PEG formalism (which is not context-free) rather than BNF. (These are not the same despite the superficial resemblance.)

That said, it might not be convenient. In general, like most questions related to the structure of parsers, the answer is going to be based less on theory and more on a combination of practicality (with reference to a specific use case) and programmer prejudice.

As is well known, purity is rarely the most practical. Most real-life parser and scanner generators deviate from the pure theoretical models in order to provide mechanisms which are easier to use, easier to implement efficiently, or more powerful. For example, the character class syntax (`[a-zA-Z]`), which is almost universal in scanner generators, is a clear extension to regular expression syntax which deliberately avoids the need to explicitly list the entire contents of the set. One could say that the listing is implicit and unambiguous in the example I just presented, but most scanner generators also allow the use of classes like `[[:alnum:]]` ("alphanumeric symbols"), where the precise list of matched symbols is either locale-dependent or, in the Unicode world, extensible in the future. Regardless, this is obviously a useful extension.

While it is true that some aspects of regular expressions are more compact than their equivalent regular grammars -- especially the Kleene star operator, which in BNF requires an additional non-terminal and thus an additional name -- there are also cases where the ability to name subexpressions makes regular grammars more compact. Many scanner generators, starting with Lex, allowed named subpatterns as another regular expression extension. Furthermore, it is possible (with some caveats) to add the Kleene star and other operators to BNF as macros, and many parser generators do so. So there is a certain convergence of notation.

As you say, one difference between scanners and parsers is that the scanner generally makes no attempt to parse the substructure of a lexeme. But it is not true that no lexeme has substructure, and these substructures often do need to be analysed. The most notorious example is probably floating point numbers, which have to be analysed into a multiplier and an exponent, and the multiplier also analysed into an integer part and a fractional part. This analysis is commonly done using primitive functions available in the scanner implementation language (such as `strtod` for C scanners), but that does mean a second lexical scan. (Using the built-in avoids the considerable inconvenience of writing a mathematically correct string-to-internal converter, which is a much more difficult problem than it first appears. Rolling your own number converter is not recommended.)

Other lexemes with internal structure include string literals (which may contain escape sequences) and a large variety of more complex lexemes available in certain languages (dates and times, IP addresses, HTML tags, etc., etc.). All of these things tend to blur the boundary between scanning and parsing. Which is fine, because, as I said, the boundary is situational and not restrained by any absolute law of nature.

Still, it is certainly the case that many lexemes do not have any interesting internal structure, and furthermore that while it is easy to rewrite a regular expression as a regular grammar, it is considerably harder to rewrite it as an unambiguous, deterministic regular grammar, much less an LALR(1) regular grammar. (This is one of the reasons scannerless parsing is often associated with PEG, but it can also be solved with GLL or GLR parsers, at a slight loss of efficiency.)

Comment: Thank you very much @rici for your very detailed answer. Your comments comfort me on the blurred boundary between scanning and parsing and the properties of BNF and regex.
Thanks also for pointing me the difficulty of making a custom string-to-float converter, I didn't think much about it because I'm using generally the standard library for that, but I know more my debt to the people who made it now.
Thank you again for your reply, it gives me plenty to think about.